# Change the font-size based on its original value by changing the browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

How can I use jQuery, JS, CSS, whatever it takes to change the font-size value by percentage, when browser size (width) is between two certain number.

e.x.

```
<div class="Fsize">Sample text<div>

<style>
//a sample size, lets say it can be anything
font-size: 100px;
</style>


<script>
//what should be here to change font-size to  for example 30% of its original value (100px), which is 30px. when browser size (width) is between 700px to 1000px.
</script>
```

I cannot use Media media-queries. Below is a sample where I used it.
The percentage in CSS changes the font-size based on the `body {font-size}`not its original value (which is 250 here).

```
<div class="font">Some Text</div>

<style>
.font {
   font-size: 250px;
  }


  @media (max-width: 600px) {  
.font {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be doing it with javascript, use [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) of css

Comment: Please read my update, any thoughts?

Comment: it changes value in percentage of parent element, so you need to set parent element original value and change child in percentage

Comment: That is the issue, I do not have access to that for some reasons. Any chance that i can do it using JS or jQuery?

Comment: yes, you can get element font-size and operate with it. you can listen to browser change width by `$(window).on("resize", function () { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

font-size property is relative to the parent element’s font size

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-prop

That means if you want to change the font size via a percentage using a media query, you need set the relative font-size for the container first.

```
.container{
  font-size:40px;
}

.font{
  font-size: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px){  
  .font {
      font-size: 200%;

  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/bisirojoquxa/1/

You can either use a container, or set the size of the font in the body element, and scale from there. I recommend using a Sass based solution for responsive font sizes, something like whats included in this:

https://github.com/dmtintner/UtilityBelt